# "Unsubscribe" from messages about limits

Tags: governorlimits

If I reach limits for my Salesforce edition I'm receiving message like "Hourly limit exceeded for processing workflow time trigger". Is there any way I can stop receiving these messages, like unsubscribe or uncheck some option?

Comment: Which edition are you using?

Comment: Unlimited edition

Comment: Stop being Salesforce administrator ;) or setup filter in your email to route them to trash.

Comment: )) thanks). I thought there could be some checkbox I'm not aware of or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce limits the number of time triggers an organization can execute per hour as follows:

- Enterprise Edition =500
- Developer Edition =50
- Unlimited Edition =1,000

Refer this link

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008m1cIAA

Comment: I know what these limits mean, I want to stop receiving messages about these limits being hit.